# Views in iOS7 moved above Navigation bar but work fine in iOS6

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7

I am unable to get the UISearchBar to display fine on iOS7. I cannot use AutoLayout as I must support the app for older versions of iOS prior to 6 also. I tried setting the container view's frame if the iOS is of version 7 and above but it does not work. I also tried topLayOutGuide length and other tips mentioned in other SO posts but I could not succeed. (EDIT:- I am using STORYBOARD)

The only thing I currently have in my code is

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

[image: Screenshot of simulator top section in iOS7]
[image: Screenshot of simulator top section in iOS6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to suggest a change to do in the `storyboard`:

tap on your `viewController` and on `attributes inspector` uncheck Under top bars

[image]

if this not work try this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

 NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
 int ver_int = [ver intValue];

 if (ver_int < 7) {
 }
 else {
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
 }

}
```

Comment: Unchecking "Under Top Bars" now shows correct view in the Storyboard which is a step forward. But when I run the app in simulator, it still does not work. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: @ilight sorry for not being too helpful, have you tried with the code I suggested?

Comment: @ilight try with my code, but removing self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: It does not work the 1st time I open a View but if I go back and come to the view again, your code works. I currently put it in ViewDiDLoad. Where can I move it to so that it works all the time?

Comment: @ilight as I wrote above you should try to put this code in viewWillAppear

Comment: Same issue even if I put it in viewWillAppear too. It does not work the 1st time

Comment: @ilight ok try in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying your code in a child viewcontroller. Worked great when I moved this to the actual viewcontroller which is embedded in UINavigationController. Thanks a lot :)